# c++ streaming into char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, char

im currently working on a c++ application which is using a c library which needs a callback implemented from my side
for example the callback is defined as this:

```
int onWrite(char *what, char *buffer, size_t size, off_t offset);
```

i have std::set which needs to be formated and written into buffer and take care of size and offset where size is buffer's size and offset how many bytes have already been processed

is there a c++ way where i can stream-like into buffer?
i think about something like this:

```
SomeSTLStandardStream stream(buffer,size);
stream.ignore(offset);  // to drop the first n offset bytes
for(it=dataset.begin();it!=dataset.end() && stream.buffer_avail()>0;it++)
    stream << *it << "|"; // format csv like for example
```

the core question i have is: is there a standard c++ way to grab just a slice of formated/streamed data and write into given buffer?

if not ill have to implement my own

i also had a look at stringstream but it doesnt seem to fit exactly to my needs cause its using its own write buffer instead of mine
and i dont know how many bytes have already been written to it too and such....

thx

Comment: There's `std::ostrstream`; it's deprecated, but it might fit your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate memory and wrap it in a string stream by using [`std::stringstream::pubsetbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf):

```
 int main()
 {
    char buf[1024];

    std::stringstream stream;

    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));

    stream<< "Hello " << "World " << std::endl;

    std::string str;
    std::getline(stream, str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    //...
}
```

Read [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and [`std::basic_stringbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf).

Comment: i already had a look at pubsetbuf. The problem i have with this is that i dont know if or how many bytes have truly been written into my buf. For example if you set your buffer size to char buf[3]={'\0'}; with pubsetbuf(buf,2); and then do rdbuf()->sputn("ab",2); rdbuf()->sputn("bb",2); the return value of both sputn will signal that everything worked, but only the first one has been actually written to my buf (dont know where the second has gone?) - so how do i know: when to stop writting? and how many bytes have already been written to my buf?