# printf int to char array with left padded spaces

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a bit of a brain dead moment.

I have to store the string representation of an `int` to a `char[]`, but the ascii representation will have to be left padded by spaces.
A `snprintf` will do the job.

```
  char data     [6];
  int msg_len = 10;
  std::snprintf(data, 6, "%*d", 5, msg_len);
  //"   10" <-- OK
```

I just wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it.
I have access to `C++11`
Also there's a a bit of a problem, I think snprintf will add also a terminating character, and I have to avoid that. 
I could have an intermediary buffer and copy that one into my data, but it would add additional complexity.

I need to do it in place, because those data structures are part of a message I have to send to a server that accepts input formatted that way.

The message looks like:

```
  struct
  {
    char first_field   [6];
    char second_field  [8];
    char data_field    [12];
  };
```

And I might need to set the second_field before having set the first one. Also I have a lot more fields to fill in, so a generic solution would be appreciated.
As long as I can convert an int to that string representation would be fine.

Comment: Well, you can use a `std::ostringstream` in c++.

Comment: I need to save to to an array of chars, it's for generating a message to send to an application that receives that kind of input. And the message is formed by several fields such as the `data` in my example. I would also avoid using streams and extra copies if possible.

Comment: You probably want to put extra requirements in your question.

Comment: I just found this code http://ideone.com/nrQfA8 from http://zverovich.net/2013/09/07/integer-to-string-conversion-in-cplusplus.html

as a fist look it seems like it will be quite easy to modify to do what I want.

Comment: IMO this snprintf is more elegant than using iostreams. (Probably faster too)

Comment: streams in the stl are not the most successful piece of code written ;-) 
At the end I ended up rolling an ad hoc limited implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your indicated constraints this may improve on your own answer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>

inline void 
unsigned_to_decimal( unsigned long number, char* buffer, std::size_t size)
{
    std::size_t i = size;
    buffer[size - 1] = '0';
    for (unsigned long n ;(n = number) > 0 && i > 0 ;) {
        buffer[--i] = '0' + n - (10 * (number /= 10));
    }
    assert(number == 0);
    std::fill(buffer,buffer + (i - (i == size)),' ');
}
```

For a demo, append:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <array>

constexpr std::size_t decimal_digits(unsigned long n)
{
    return n / 10 > 0 ? 1 + decimal_digits(n / 10) : 1;
}


int main()
{
    const std::size_t max_digits = decimal_digits(ULONG_MAX);
    std::cout << "Print decimal 0, UINT_MAX, ULONG_MAX "
        "from left-padded char buffer, size " << max_digits << ":-\n"; 
    for (auto ul : std::array<unsigned long,3>{0,UINT_MAX,ULONG_MAX}) {
        char buf[max_digits];
        std::fill(buf,buf + max_digits,'?');
        std::cout << '[' << std::string(buf,buf + max_digits) << "]\n";
        unsigned_to_decimal(ul,buf,max_digits);
        std::cout << '[' << std::string(buf,buf + max_digits) << "]\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which runs like:

```
Print decimal 0, UINT_MAX, ULONG_MAX from left-padded char buffer, size 20:-
[????????????????????]
[                   0]
[????????????????????]
[          4294967295]
[????????????????????]
[18446744073709551615]
```

(g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic, GCC 5.3.1)

Comment: it's not the most easy function to read, but that is quite impressive! thanks!

Comment: For the fun of it, I ran a little test on a 100Million iterations with a random generated number. with `std::uniform_int_distribution`. With gcc 5.2.1 on an i7, compiled with `O3`
extra copy:
seconds     : 5.435177
your solution:
seconds     : 4.209649

Answer (score 5):

this can be achived by combination of `std::ostringstream`, and io manipulators, such as: `std::setfill`, `std::setw` and other:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(7) << 1015;
std::string str = s.str();
std::cout << str << std::endl; // outputs "0001015"
```

Comment: I really need to save it to an array of chars, to avoid that extra string.

Comment: @dau_sama, well, you can copy stream contents to your char array like this: `strncpy(data,s.str().c_str(),sizeof(data))`. Don't forget to null-terminate array (if required) and replace `sizeof` if using `char*` instead of array

Comment: I could, however that would create a new string from the stringstream, and  I wanted to do it in place for performance reasons. Unfortunately it is a really time sensitive piece of code.

Comment: @dau_sama, well, you can probably look for an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358669/c-streaming-into-char-array), or write your own stream or templated formatted write function.

Comment: http://www.fastformat.org/documentation/index.html may help but it's yet another dependency.
Writing my own templated write function is an option, but internally it will have to use a  `printf` with an intermediate buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Andrei R. already showed an elegant way, so I won't repeat it, but I'll answer your other questions.

> Also there's a a bit of a problem, I think snprintf will add also a terminating character, and I have to avoid that.

There is no way to avoid writing null with `snprintf`.

> I could have an intermediary buffer and copy that one into my data, but it would add additional complexity.

That is the typical way to achieve what you want. This approach can also be taken using the result from `std::ostringstream` as the intermediary buffer.

Depending on what you intend to use the non null terminated string for, there might be approaches.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I rolled out my own simplistic solution, which fits my needs for now.
I only handle unsigned values and no locale, but it works for what I need to do.

```
inline void unsigned_to_decimal( unsigned long number, char* buffer, std::size_t size)
{
    char* start = buffer;
    char* end   = buffer + size;

    if(number == 0)
    {
        *buffer++ = '0';
    }
    else
    {
        while( number != 0 )
        {
            *buffer++ = '0' + number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        std::reverse( start, buffer );

        //need to fill the remaining characters with spaces
        std::fill(buffer, end, ' ');
        std::rotate(start, start + std::distance(start, buffer), end);
    }
}
```