# Streaming into `char` array with `ostream` - how to get characters written count?

Tags: c++, stringstream

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16360560/12307590) shows how to write to an array with `stringstream`, but can we obtain the total number of characters written? Surely the `stringstream` has some information to know where to put the next character, but I don't know how to access it.

The OP of the linked question even asks this in a comment but I wanted a separate question to be sure.

I know `ostrstream` has a `pcount` method, unfortunately, it is deprecated.

Comment: [`tellp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp)?

Comment: “unfortunately, it is deprecated” — deprecated doesn’t mean it doesn’t work. It means only that it **might** be removed from the standard in the future. **If** it gets removed, sane implementations will continue to provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::ostrstream` class itself is deprecated.

Use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead, which has a [`tellp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp) method.

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    std::ostringstream stream;

    stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));

    auto start = stream.tellp();
    stream << "Hello " << "World " << std::endl;
    auto written = stream.tellp() - start;

    //...
}
```